# iOS App Title in Settings

Tags: ios, settings, info.plist, spotlight

So the question is pretty straightforward:

My app has a pretty long title, so I have to make `BundleDisplayName` a shortened version of it for it not to be clipped on the home screen.

However, in Spotlight search or when editing the app's settings bundle, there would be enough space for the long/full title to be displayed.

Is it possible to have a different title being displayed in these locations?

Comment: I just checked, I had an app with a long name which I shortened down using BundleDisplayName. When I do a search on my actual device is shows only the shortened version of the app name. I guess that makes sense as that is the only name a user knows or sees

Comment: But that kinda sucks, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spotlight is used for searching. Users recognize your app by you app's `BundleDisplayName`, if you provide a different name for your app in spotlight, it may mislead users and it is inappropriate in my opinion.

BTW I didn't find any references about this , so I think there is no way to achieve by now.

Comment: While this is true, for the normal display name I currently only remove the last ~5 chars. Also, on Mac for example, 'System Preferences' also shows up when you search for 'Settings' ;)